# How to make a Quasar q-page-container child use full height of its grandparent?

Tags: html, css, quasar-framework

I've got a Quasar layout, and a component that I need to fill 100% of the height of the `q-page-container` element. The problem is that the container does not fully expand to cover the entire height (unlike the drawer, which, using absolute positioning, does).

All CSS-tricks I've seen to tackle this problem interfere with the properties of the parent containers, which I'm reluctant to do to make sure I don't break any properties necessary for internal Quasar layout. Setting the child `div` of the container to `height: 100%` has no impact, setting it to an absolute value such as `100px` does correctly set the height, but I need it to adapt to the browser viewport.

I've set up a fiddle to illustrate [the problem here](https://jsfiddle.net/u7kd9nyq/5/).

In this case I'd like `#troublemaker` to fill entire height of its container - or rather, its grandparent minus the header height, since the parent container simply expands to whatever content is inside.

*PS: CSS layout and positioning have always seemed counter intuitive to me, so if anyone has some good advice on resources to learn how to better understand the logics of it I would appreciate it immensely!*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think `q-page-container` need a `q-page`.

So just replace your `div` by a `q-page` and it's work.
here is your fiddle fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/uab1rnjh/2/

Or if you really want to work with a `div`.
You can do the trick with css: `height: calc(100vh - 50px);`
Here is your fiddle with a div: https://jsfiddle.net/yghL6so8/2/

In the documentation, you can see QPageContainer encapsulates a QPage.
at: https://quasar.dev/layout/page#QPageContainer-API

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This works for the `q-page` element, but if I'm including another component, this comes with it's *own* `div`, which I cannot specify as a `q-page` without internally modifying the component itself. Also, using the CSS helper classes `fit` and `full-height` does not work. `style='height: 100vh; padding-top: -50px;'` seems to do the trick though, in this particular case. Is that a viable solution?

Comment: The above should be `margin-top`, not `padding-top`.

Comment: You can do the trick by doing `height: calc(100vh - 50px);`

Here is a fiddle to explain: https://jsfiddle.net/yghL6so8/2/

Comment: This is pretty cool! How did I miss this all this time? I think this comprises the cleanest solution to this issue.

Comment: This  is a winner: .google-map {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: gray;
    position: none;
}

Comment: This will only work if you set your Navigation Header to 50px. However if you have another sizes you cannot stay consistent here. Keep that in mind to have a workaround with $variables or smth else.

Answer (score 18):

If you have a `div` inside a `q-page`, I found the proper way to do this is to let the `div` inherit the `min-height` CSS property from the `q-page` component.

I updated the fiddle to show it: https://jsfiddle.net/u39qbrpj/4/

```css
#troublemaker {
  min-height: inherit;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: This is useful! Somehow, however, my QScrollArea needs `height` set instead of `min-height` in order for its contents (a QTable) to appear. The parent QPage, however, apparenty uses `min-height`. I now know how to inherit `min-height`, but can I somehow set `height` to `min-height`? Or should I approach this differently?

Comment: I actually found the solution myself by studying https://codepen.io/cp-tof06/pen/bGdKXpW
Instead of style attributes, I am now using `class="column full-height"` on the QScrollArea. Apparently, the flex layout then makes it all magically working (just using `col` classes on the QScrollArea and QTable within, without any style attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Using a q-page inside a q-page-container is certainly the most common way. Per the doc a q-page must be in a q-page container. However, if you want to put a div in a container and have it fill the container you can use `class="fit"` and the div will fill the entire container.

Comment: I tried this: inside a q-page put a `<div class="fit"><q-btn .../></div>`  but the div does not take full height.